# How to make a protected range appear normal in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, permissions

I have a project in Google spreadsheets shared with several other users. There are sensitive formulas throughout that I have protected to prevent accidental deletion or overwrite by the other users. This works great to keep the formulas safe. However, when the other users view a protected range, it is covered in a distracting gray hatch-striping.

I would really like these protected cells to appear without the stripe pattern for the other users. Is there a way to turn off this special formatting for protected ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Uncheck view protected range from google script macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281817/uncheck-view-protected-range-from-google-script-macro) it looks as though you might either have to risk accidental deletion/overwriting, have other users suffer the distraction or uncheck "Protected Range" in the view menu. A suggestion was to "Include an image with screenshotted text that tells them to goto View > Protected Ranges".